# Error occurred during a cryptographic operation

Tags: content-editor

After upgrading from Sitecore 7.5 to 8 .when i try to open Control panel in CMS i get an Error saying "Error occurred during a cryptographic operation."

Note : i do have an entry for machine in my config

[image]

Comment: Can you check if you have : <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="512000" executionTimeout="600" enableKernelOutputCache="false" />
inside   </system.web> on web.config ?